# Dependent Origination and "vast emptiness"

Tags: pratityasamutpada, sunyata

Can emptiness due to dependent origination be logically connected to the "vast emptiness"
of Bodhidharma and Huineng?
A possible connection is that "vast emptiness" of space is the ultimate source of everything that happens into it, which is insignificant relative to its vast and empty support (container). 
In this way emptiness is something vastly more substantial than the little substantialities we perceive as such using our ordinary mind, including seemingly grandiose ideas like the cyclical ever-recurring universe
or the self-referential ability of the mind that results in the ego consciousness.
So is this the main point of dependent origination? That it ultimately leads to vast empty space as the source of everything?

Comment: hi can you please be more specific on what you are referring to with "emptiness due to dependent origination"? The traditional Pali descriptions of DO make no mention of emptiness, so I can only guess you're referring to Nagarjuna's MKK?

Comment: yes I mean emptiness as lack of permanent substantiality in the manner of  "B happens only if A happens", so if we remove A then B is removed too.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> In this way emptiness is something vastly more substantial

then

> I mean emptiness as lack of permanent substantiality

which seems contradictory.

You might like to read about the [Dharmakaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmak%C4%81ya), and the cosmic or primordial Buddha. I take this to be a metaphor, for how within all dependent origination, in all thought streams and situations that arise, there is also the potential for Awakening, that this is a foundational potential that co-arises with any other phenomena.

Emptiness or rather Sunyata, is about how nothing is permanent or exists in isolation. Ultimately, recognising that, frames existence in terms of potential, rather than substances or substantiality. We bring the mind of untangling and non-attachment to dependent arising, and that is the path towards Unshakable Liberation from causes and conditions, and that faces the direction of Awakening.

Comment: My 1st reference to emptiness refers to the "emptiness of the vast space" while the 2nd refers to objects that appear within that space, which acts as the container. I view the 1st emptiness as substantial in the sense that it is permanent indeed, ever-existing on its own, not as an isolated  "thing" but as the ultimate container of everything that could possibly ever appear... So I do not see any contradiction.  That way, Awakening is "seeing into" the procedure by which that seemingly "inert" container generates and holds the array of objects that appear to our senses.

Comment: @exp8j: Using the same word, for different things, in the same context, is just going to confuse things. When you say 'of the vast space', you mean space-time, the vacuum seperate to particles? Because it doesn't work like that, matter bends space, bent space changes how matter moves - whether the cosmos is closed like a bubble, or will expand forever depends how much matter there is, & we seem to be on a knife-edge between. If you mean Sunyata, or Dependent Origination, use the proper terms. Emptiness is a confusing translation from Sanskrit *at best*

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that "emptiness" as regards dependent origination is customarily intended to mean "insignificance" rather than "spatial vacuity", the latter pointing to the "vast emptiness" of Bodhidharma and Huineng and incorporating both tangible objects and mental phenomena? My point in this post is to explore the view that tangible objects and mental phenomena are insignificant manifestations of a vast substratum which appears as a spatially vacuous & inert  container to the ignorant but as the fundamental living reality to the enlightened.

Comment: @exp8j: "Bodhi really has no tree
Nor is clear mirror the stand
Nothing’s there initially
So where can the dustmotes land?" Huineng's point isn't that nothing is real, or significant. But that the original ground is Awakened, which breaks the chains of causes & conditions. This is Sudden Enlightenment doctrine. Emptiness in the Buddhist context, Sunyata, is about dependence on causes & conditions, the lack of essence, permanence, or independence. While we can think this through easily for objects, turning on the nature of the self, evokes vastness, the recognition our personal borders shift

Comment: @exp8j: Do you know Alayavijnana in the Mahayana elaboration of the sense-gates into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses ? The Buddhist picture is not like Plato's forms: special secret sauce for the well-read. I'd compare Eighth Consciousness to the faculting accessing the 'memesphere', the space where ideas can propagate independently of medium. It's not *more real*, it's just one aspect. Zen cultivates the skill of multiple perspectives & framings, to liberate from dependent origination, from conditioning. 'Vast like space' is ordinary mind, known as a corner of the universe

Comment: Yes it's a vast shift of perspective to acknowledge that infinite space is not a dead container but 
a living entity, a boiling ground of potentiality, which resonates well with Alayavijnana as "All-encompassing foundation consciousness" or "causal consciousness", which indeed breaks the chains of causes & conditions as perceived from an unelightened viewpoint. It's not the wind that moves the flag, it's the mind-wind-flag trio that arises with a certain "suchness"  from the original ground.

Comment: So the crucial thing is to achieve a radical qualitative breakthrough towards a higher "dimension" and keep it, as e.g. human life is relative to animal. We can be infinitely "creative" & "liberated" and still not touch the original ground.

Comment: Physicists understand the cosmos better than average, do you think they're more enlightened? *"after enlightenment, mountains are once again mountains and waters once again waters"* - Dogen. It is not about finding the 'more real', it is about a change of perspective like waking up from a dream. Understanding Alayavijnana, storehouse consciousness, cannot solve the problem of suffering. However elaborate your cosmology it can only at best help guide people towards the important thing: the cessation of the causes of suffering. Buddhist ideas only make sense as orientated around that lodestone

Comment: "guide people towards the important thing". For me that is already enough. Living in some right direction, suitable for each one's temperament. The rest will come naturally. We are not alone in the world. We are embedded in it, in its silent intelligence,  as everything is.